# Micro USB b connection detector

Tags: battery-charging, cables, usb-device, android, connect

Is there a way to detect if there is a Micro USB B cable physically inserted into a micro  USB B receptacle, even if it is just a cable (with nothing attached to it). in android device

Comment: For microB, I suspect you only have the ID pin as a partial solution, Its uncommon for phones to have a separate detection contact for micro B, most of them only rely on the data pin and 5V voltage to tell if something is connected.

Comment: IF you can add extra circuitry then the capacity of the cable should be detectable.

Comment: It's conceivable that you MAY be able to do this using the internal hardware driven at the lowest possible level, but that's only a maybe. eg if you can get access to the hardware to drive individual pins on/off and detect changes on other pins from parallel capacitive coupling between conductors.

Answer (score 1):

MAYBE, just MAYBE you could use shield for that. In normal circumstances, shield is ground, but the most important thing is that the ground pin of microusb is ground, shield doesn't exactly have to be ground.

I'm not sure if there is a correct way to do that, it requires testing, but, here is something I would try and see what happens: 
[image]

So when there is nothing connected, detector line will have like 4.5V (logic HIGH), and when you plug something in, the shield is connected to ground via cable or target device, so detector line is 0V (logic LOW). Will that work with all cables? Do all cables have shield and ground internally connected? Or are they only connected internally in target devices like phone? No idea. You'll have to try that. If you get some noise on detector, divide resistors by 10 (both of them). I just picked those values to minimize current loss, but we are in the microamp area here, you probably won't care. Anyway, I would give this design a shot. Just measure with the multimeter output on DETECTOR line and see if it works.

Comment: +1 It's a maybe - but you say that clearly - worth investigating. If the phantom downvoter knows clearlyt that this doesn't ever work then it would be helpful if they share what they know, if only in a comment.